# Python urllib request to Google sites slow

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to make urllib requests to http://google.com in Python 3 (I rewrote it in 2.7 using urllib2 as well, same issue). Below is some of my code:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36')]

def makeRequest():
    search = 'http://google.com'

    print('About to search...')
    response = opener.open(search).read()
    print('Done')

makeRequest()
```

When I run this code, it runs in about 14 seconds:

```
real    0m14.386s
user    0m0.087s
sys     0m0.027s
```

This seems to be the case with any Google site (Gmail, Google Play, etc.). When I change the search variable to a different site, such as Stackoverflow or Twitter, it runs in well under half a second:

```
real    0m0.277s
user    0m0.085s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the slow response from Google?

Comment: I ran your code. It took 0.451 seconds.

Comment: @mchant : The timing might depend on your internet speed also. So it can be diff from his.

Comment: @Gunjan I'm using ethernet and am getting 112Mbps/98Mbps according to testmy.net, so I don't think my internet speeds are an issue. Google also loads instantly in the browser, which is why I thought it might be a Python issue.

Comment: @user139260 : I was referring to the time difference between mchant and your code execution time.

Comment: This is really odd. I have a similar issue. cURL et al are really fast loading the url in question. Python's (3) urllib.request takes forever.

Comment: I am running into this exact same issue. I wrote a python irc bot that fetches url information, and it is fast for everything besides google sites.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `ping` or `traceroute` to google.com and others sites to compare the time delay to see if the DNS issue.

Second, you can use `wireshark` to sniffer every packets to see if something wrong with the communication.

I think may be DNS issue, but I can't make sure that.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I'm getting 8ms responses from google.com but in the upper 60's when pinging twitter.com. Traceroutes to gmail finish in <0.2 seconds, but it my code still takes >12 seconds in python. I haven't tried wireshark, but I'll run it later when I have some more time.


Edit: I also tried changing my DNS to Google's DNS, but the issue still persists.